# is this the best anagram checking solution?

Tags: anagram

I am looking for an efficient solution to check if two strings are anagrams, but char table/dictionary checking may not be a good solution for unicode. I have come up a solution, but I don't know how to prove it mathematically correct. The formula is in the express as " (a + b) = (c + d) and a XOR b XOR c XOR d = 0 ==> (a,b) and (c,d) are anagrams". Maybe you can help me. The following is an implementation.

```
def isAnagram(s1: String, s2: String): Boolean = {
  if (s1.length != s2.length) return false
  else {
    var numVal = 0
    var bitVal = 0
    for (i <- 0 until s1.length) {
      numVal += s1(i) - s2(i)
      bitVal ^= s1(i) ^ s2(i)
    }

  return numVal == 0 && bitVal == 0
}
```

Comment: you could bring it down from O(n) to O(n/2)

Comment: @shyam  O(n) = O(n/2)  (the same class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

icepack's counter example is incorrect, as `1 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 2 ^ 4 ^ 3 = 2`, not `0`.

Here's a better counter example: `s1 = (5, 0, 5)` and `s2 = (1, 4, 5)`.

`5 + 0 + 5 = 1 + 4 + 5`

`5 ^ 0 ^ 5 ^ 1 ^ 4 ^ 5 = 0`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in real case, all characters' values are larger than zero. I'd like you give an example without zero value.

Comment: No problem, what about s1 = (5, 2), s2 = (3, 4)? Hope that clears it up.

Comment: I'm glad you like it, it'll be great if you can choose my solution as the answer to your question.

Comment: I assumed the XOR in the question isn't bitwise but valuewise.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions aren't good enough.
Here is an opposite example:
`s1 = (1,5,3), s2 = (2,4,3)`

`1+5+3=9=2+4+3`

`1 ^ 5 ^ 3 ^ 2 ^ 4 ^ 3 = 0`

Comment: That holds for valuewise XOR. For bitwise the correct example would be the one above.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the easiest way to find two strings are anagram or not.

```
<?php
$str1=$_POST['str1'];
$str2=$_POST['str2'];
$arr1=str_split($str1);
$arr2=str_split($str2);
sort($arr1);
sort($arr2);
echo (($arr1==$arr2) ? "The given string is anagram" : "The given string is not a anagram"); 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class anagram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 1st String");

        String r1=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter 2nd String");

        String r2=sc.nextLine();
        if(r1.length()!=r2.length()) System.out.println("not a Anagram");

        char[] s1=r1.toCharArray();
        char[] s2=r2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(s1);
        Arrays.sort(s2);
        boolean f= Arrays.equals(s1, s2);

        if(f==false) System.out.println("not a Anagram");
        else System.out.println("its a Anagram");
    }
}
```